# Android Fragment animation on replacement doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation

I've got an activity in which there are 2 fragments which changes basing on a button click.

I'd like to show an animation when the replacement appens, so i searched for the code and here's what i concluded:

```
public void displayView(int page){
    switch (page){
        case 1:
            FragmentHome fragmentHome = new FragmentHome();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment, fragmentHome)
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).commit();
            break;
        case 2:
            FragmentHomeBack fragmentHomeBack = new FragmentHomeBack();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment, fragmentHomeBack)
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.accelerate_decelerate_interpolator, android.R.anim.anticipate_interpolator).commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

I don't know why but the animations don't works, the new fragment just replace the other without animation.

Here's the activity layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_master"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/space10"
tools:context="context">
<include
    android:id="@+id/ll_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/space5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space5"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/space15"
    layout="@layout/menu"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ll_left">

</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/xlink"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:layout_height="70dp" />
```

The frame layout "fragment_holder" is where the Fragments are.

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should do the trick buddy. I have the same code and it works well.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.layout_container, fragment)
                .commit();
```

But..

I see what is the difference in our code. Try setting customAnimations before replace to see what happens.

And I have a suggestion to improve your code. In your "if" or "switch" statement set the fragment like

```
Fragment fragment;
    if(page==0){
      fragment = new MyFragment();
    }else{
      fragment = new MySecondFragment();
    }
```

then you only have this code once

```
getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.layout_container, fragment)
                .commit();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this.

Comment: getChildFragmentManager()  can't be resolved, what about getSUpportFragmentManager() or only getFragmentManager()?

Comment: In my code I have. Fragment inside a fragment, that's why I use getChildFragmentManager, you have to use getSupportFragmentManager  if you are loading them in your activity

Comment: getFragmentManager is to use with Activities. getSupportFragmentManager is to be use with retro-compatibles libraries AppcompatActivity that for you to develop ups with fragment for android under version 4 if i remember correctly. getChildFragmentManager can be use to load a fragment inside another fragment. Give it a try.